# how can I get the whole array's value from jp@gc-JSON Path Assertion

Tags: jmeter

I use jmeter's JDBC Request to check respons data from SQL:

```
the JDBC request's data is:
name_us_#=6
name_us_1=Fashion Goods
name_us_2=Women's clothing
name_us_3=Home
name_us_4=Men's clothing
name_us_5=Accessories
name_us_6=Children's wear
```

I can use `${name_us_1}` to get value `'Fashion Goods'`.

But how can I get all of the JDBC request's data?

Answer (score 0):

You can define "Result variable name" in the JDBC Request sampler

[image: JDBC Result Variable Name]

This way you will be able to access the whole ResultSet as a JMeter Variable:

[image: JMeter Variable from JDBC]

Once done you should be able to access it from scripting test elements, i.e. [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor):

[image: JSR223 Results JDBC JMeter]

See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article to learn more about working with JDBC test elements data in JMeter tests.